# xdebug and WAMP - still Waiting for connection

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I tried very, very much solutions for install xdebug with WAMP, but i have still communicat "Waiting for connection".

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension_ts="C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts-86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="c:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

i have this in both php.ini (/php and /apache).

but i can enable extension php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts-86_64.dll in WAMP. If i check this, then WAMP is reset and still is uncheck.

I have Windows 7 (64x).

```
Sometimes i have error:

Failed loading ”C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll”
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_phar.dll' - .\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_phar.dll'
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/php_xsl.dll' in Unknown on line 0
<br />

PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

but very rarely.

How can i make with this? Please help. Still "Waiting for connection"

Answer (score 0):

A few issues. You're using PHP 5.3 and loading the extension with:

zend_extension_ts="C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9-nts-86_64.dll"

This line is wrong in two places:

- Since PHP 5.3, `zend_extension_ts` no longer exists and you have to use `zend_extension=`
- You use the **nts** version while the ..._ts line indicates you use the TS version of PHP

I would suggest you make sure you have no zend_extension*= and extension= lines mentioning anything of Xdebug, and then refer to the [wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php).